# Android Drawing bitmap and button on canvas by X Y Positions

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, draw, imagebutton

i'm new into android and i have some problems with my app. Any help will be appreciated :)

I have drawing bitmap on canvas by xpositon and ypostion by sensors (when i'm moving my phone, bitmaps are moving )

I need to create moving clickable button on center of my  bitmaps and when i click them i will go to next activity .

Bitmaps are drawing perfectly but idont know how to draw buttons on them, buttons that will be moving with my bitmap by the same values of x and y. How i can do that?

This is my piece of code:

```
    private void updateBall() {

        // Calculate new speed
        // xVelocity += (xAcceleration * frameTime);
        // yVelocity += (yAcceleration * frameTime);

        // Calc distance travelled in that time
        // float xS = (xVelocity/2)*frameTime;
        // float yS = (yVelocity/2)*frameTime;

        // Add to position negative due to sensor
        // readings being opposite to what we want!
        // xPosition -= xS;

        // ------------------------------- MOVING Y --------------------------------------------------

        by = (-IMG_H + ddy) / 2f;
        ay = by / 90f;

        float dy = (ay * zAcceleration + by);

        if (Math.abs(zAcceleration) < 90 && Math.abs(yAcceleration) > 100)
            yPosition -= (yPosition - dy) / 20.;
        else if (zAcceleration > 0) {
            if (yPosition > -IMG_H) {
                if (Math.abs(yAcceleration) > 100) {
                    dy = (ay * 90 + by);
                    yPosition -= (yPosition - dy) / 20.;
                } else {
                    yPosition = -IMG_H;
                }
            }

        } else {
            if (yPosition < IMG_H) {
                if (Math.abs(yAcceleration) > 100) {
                    dy = (-ay * 90 + by);
                    yPosition -= (yPosition - dy) / 20.;
                } else {
                    yPosition = ddy;
                }
            }
        }

        // block y
        yPosition = 0;

        // ------------------------------- MOVING X --------------------------------------------------

        // For understanding :)
        // ddx= 1280-(float)display.getWidth();

        ax = -IMG_W / (180f);// -2*xStart);
        bx = -ax * xStart;

        // xStart pozycja początkowa

        if (xAcceleration > xStart && xAcceleration <= 180 + xStart) {
            dx = (ax * xAcceleration + bx);
            if (dirr == false) {
                xPosition = dx;
                dirr = true;
            }

            xPosition -= (xPosition - dx) / 20.;
            xPosition1 = xPosition + IMG_W;
        } else {
            dx1 = (ax * (xAcceleration - 180f) + bx);
            if (dirr == true) {
                xPosition1 = dx1;
                dirr = false;
            }

            xPosition1 -= (xPosition1 - dx1) / 20.;
            xPosition = xPosition1 + IMG_W;

        }

        xPosition = 0;
        xPosition1 = 0;
        // xPosition=yPosition=150;
        /*
         * if (xPosition > xmax) { xPosition = xmax; } else if (xPosition < 0) {
         * xPosition = 0; }
         */
        /*
         * if (yPosition > ymax) { yPosition = ymax; } else if (yPosition < 0) {
         * yPosition = 0; }
         */

        // Print values
        Log.i("QLA", " x: " + xAcceleration + "   dx: " + dx + "    dx1: "+ dx1 + "  xpos: " + xPosition + " " + " xpos1: " + xPosition1);

    }

    // I've chosen to not implement this method
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Unregister the listener
        sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
        super.onStop();
    }

    public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
        public CustomDrawableView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            Bitmap ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.test);
            final int dstWidth = 1280;
            final int dstHeight = 960;
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball, dstWidth, dstHeight, true);

            Bitmap ball1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.tt);
            final int dstWidth1 = 1280;
            final int dstHeight1 = 960;
            mBitmap1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(ball1, dstWidth1, dstHeight1, true);
            // mWood = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            // R.drawable.wood);

            /*
             * ImageButton star = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
             * star.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void
             * onClick(View view) { Intent myIntent = new
             * Intent(view.getContext(), Main.class);
             * startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
             * overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out); }
             * 
             * });
             */
            // ImageView ddss=star.getDrawable();

        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmap;
            // canvas.drawBitmap(mWood, 0, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, xPosition, yPosition, null);

            // ss.getChildAt(0).setX();

            final Bitmap bitmap1 = mBitmap1;
            // canvas.drawBitmap(mWood, 0, 0, null);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, xPosition1, yPosition, null);

            invalidate();

        }
    }

// END of class
};
```

AND XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:id="@+id/layout">


  <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

   <Button

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="sdgvgvgfcvcv"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

  </FrameLayout>


<ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imageView1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
          android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
          android:src="@drawable/vinetka" 
          android:orientation="horizontal"/> 

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, its finally working great thanks to "gabe" and this - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646929/changing-position-of-a-button). You can always move whole relative layout inside absolute layout - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294590/set-the-absolute-position-of-a-view-in-android)

in my class variables i add :

```
    Button button;
    private int myNewX = 0;
    private int myNewY = 0;
```

on update function:

```
myNewX = (int)xAcceleration;
myNewY = (int)yAcceleration;

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = 
                (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
            absParams.x = myNewX;
            absParams.y = myNewY;
            button.setLayoutParams(absParams);
```

And XML File:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:id="@+id/layout"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:orientation="horizontal" >
>
>     <FrameLayout
>         android:id="@+id/preview"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:visibility="visible" >
>
>
>     </FrameLayout>
>
>
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/imageView1"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:adjustViewBounds="true"
>         android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
>         android:orientation="horizontal"
>         android:scaleType="centerCrop"
>         android:src="@drawable/vinetka" />
>
>
>      <Button
>       android:id="@+id/button"
>       android:layout_width="188dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Button"
>         android:layout_x="130px"
>         android:layout_y="390px"
>
>
> />
>
> </AbsoluteLayout>
> ```

THANKS FOR HELP!

Answer (score 4):

I would put your

```
CustomDrawableView
```

in a `FrameLayout`

and add the buttons to the `FrameLayout` then position your button with `setX() setY()`
or with a margin if your app needs to run pre API Level 11

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <CustomDrawableView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              />

    <Button

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/myButtonText"
            android:gravity="center"
            />

</FrameLayout>
```

now your Button will get added over the CustomDrawableView and you can use it like a normal Button.

Comment: It's not working can you look at my code , what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is not working? if the button does not show add your button after the CustomView otherwise the button is behind the view and you dont see it.

Comment: you're very welcome. Would you mind to accept the answer as correct if it is working. This also increases your accept rating, making people more likely to help you.